# Get rid of this Strict Standards warning

Tags: php, warnings

I'm trying to get rid of this warning from my wordpress installation.
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in xxxxx on line 67

The line with the "faulty code" is this one

```
$wp_theme_name = next(explode('/themes/', $stylesheet_directory_uri));
```

However, if I do pass the value per reference as requested, the WP doesn't load anymore.

Can you please help me to understand how to fix this?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Passing a variable by reference on the function call was removed in php 5.4 (you add it in the function definition now).  WordPress dies silently oftentimes, so it's loading, but you're just causing a php fatal error.

Comment: This is a **PHP** issue, that merely happens in the *context* of WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because you do the `explode()` call inside the `next()` call. The reason I think is, by strict standards you shouldn't pass a function to a function like this, because, like @AndrewBartel said, of reference, which would be missing. Doing it like shown below should work and would be correct:

```
$nval = explode( '/themes/', $stylesheet_directory_uri );
$wp_theme_name = next( $nval );
```

Comment: My pleasure, I didn't explain that optimal though, I think. Take a look at [“Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference” error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9848295/2505105) for more information. @AndreaMoro